# Facebook Attribute Mapping with StormPath to retrieve the Facebook ID

Tags: facebook, stormpath

This is driving me cray. I am trying to retrieve the Facebook id after logging in. I am assuming I have to use the attribute mapping in order to achieve this? Any thoughts?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heyo, Just thought I'd reply here too in case anyone else has questions about this.

I looked at the [Facebook scopes reference page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/), and it says that `public_profile` is the scope that contains the user ID. So, I went to my Facebook Directory, and under 'Provider Configuration' on the 'Scopes' tab, I added `public_profile`. Under the 'Attribute Mappings' tab, I added `id` as the Attribute Name and set `customData.id` as the 'Stormpath Field Name'.

When users log in to my web app using their Facebook credentials, their ID is saved directly to their account's customData:

```
{
  "id": "1260737122323"
}
```

To grab this data from the Account's customData and display it on the profile page of the [React-Express sample project](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-express-react-example), you need to do two things:

1. Ensure that the `web.me.expand.customData` config is set to true in order to have the custom data fields populated,
2. Add a new field on the profile page with `name="customData.id"`, like this:

[image]

This is covered in the docs under the [Access custom data fields by prefixing field names with customData section](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-react/blob/master/docs/api.md#userprofileform).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of these Facebook scopes is a little confusing, the properties on "public_profile" are actually available on the root of the Facebook user object, so in Stormpath you want to map `id` to `customData.public_profile.id`.

Comment: Thanks Robert! So,  Attribute Name: id Stormpath Field Names: customData.public_profile.id  ?

Comment: Yep, that should do it.

Comment: I am getting an error when console.logging. I am using react. static      contextTypes = {
    user: React.PropTypes.object
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.context.user.id)

Comment: It may be best if you contact support@stormpath.com and share you code so that we have the full context.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it almost seems like the response was automated with a link to documentation that provides no answer. Is there someone that works there that specializes in react...

Comment: @user002731 please send over your code so we can take a closer look. thanks!